# How to show user location on a custom image without a mapview

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, mapkit, core-location, mercator

I have a custom photoshop image of an area.

It is mostly rectangular, so I have taken the coordinates of the 4 corners using Google maps.

I would like to translate these 4 corners to x and y axis on that image alone and then use Core Location to display the user's location within those 4 corners (anything outside of that is not necessary).

Can I do this without using a mapview? I really don't need any other functionality outside that small area. Or do I have to overlay a custom tile on mapkit, limit the view and zoom on that area and work from there? (which seems more resource demanding than if there were a Mercator coordinates way of doing this)

Any good tutorials appreciated!

Comment: Please read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

While it's certainly possible to translate latitude and longitude to x,y coordinates on an image, it's usually more beneficial to use an `MKOverlayView` (as you described in your question) due to the free functionality you get: current position, annotations, zoom, etc.

One of the projects I've worked on in recent years benefited from having our custom map graphic surrounded by the Apple (or Google) map tiles -- it ended up giving everything a little bit more geographical context.

Comment: Okay I see. Will try that. Were the custom tiles difficult to produce? One thing I need though is multiple usable buttons on top of that image showing the device's location. Wonder if it will display nicely or not.

Comment: Hm I've managed to get the overlay on there. Problem is I need selectable buttons on top of that. I'd rather not change their alpha values. Is there a way to make the blue location dot pop up above the buttons?

Comment: You could put the buttons in a separate UIView above the one containing your map, or you could turn them into [annotations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html) and add them directly to the map. Depending on what functionality you need will determine which of those is more appropriate.

Comment: Annotations are out I think because the buttons will remember a state and show their selected image when tapped. (You can also unselect them by tapping again). The only problem I have with the Uiview on top of the map is that it covers the user's location icon. (blue dot) I just need to find a way to get that location view and redraw it or translate it to the top.